# devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service active: failed (Result: exit-code)

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack

i'm trying to install openstack on a dedicated machine with 4GB ram on Ubuntu 21.10, i faced a lot of issues and managed to troubleshoot them thanks to existing thread.
this time i can't identify the problem or finding any topic about
i tried ./unstack.sh then FORCE=yes ./stack many times and the same problem appear
here's the last lines of stack.sh

```
2021-10-31 17:08:11.928 | × devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service - Devstack devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 |      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 |      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-10-31 18:00:13 CET; 7min ago
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 |    Main PID: 79288 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 |         CPU: 4.387s
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 |
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack systemd[1]: devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack systemd[1]: devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service: Unit process 80255 (neutron-ovn-met) remains ru>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack systemd[1]: devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service: Unit process 80256 (neutron-ovn-met) remains ru>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.929 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack systemd[1]: devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service: Unit process 80266 (privsep-helper) remains run>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack systemd[1]: devstack@q-ovn-metadata-agent.service: Consumed 4.257s CPU time.
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack neutron-ovn-metadata-agent[80255]: INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] (80255) wsgi exited, is_accepting>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack neutron-ovn-metadata-agent[80256]: DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Acquired lock "singleton_l>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack neutron-ovn-metadata-agent[80255]: DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Acquired lock "singleton_l>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack neutron-ovn-metadata-agent[80255]: DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Releasing lock "singleton_>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | Oct 31 18:00:13 devstack neutron-ovn-metadata-agent[80256]: DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Releasing lock "singleton_>
2021-10-31 17:08:11.930 | +^[[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1         ^[(B^[[m exit_trap
2021-10-31 17:08:11.997 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                 ^[(B^[[m local r=3
2021-10-31 17:08:12.030 | ++^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                 ^[(B^[[m jobs -p
2021-10-31 17:08:12.049 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                 ^[(B^[[m jobs=46197
2021-10-31 17:08:12.057 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                 ^[(B^[[m [[ -n 46197 ]]
2021-10-31 17:08:12.063 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                 ^[(B^[[m [[ -n /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2021-10-31-173213 ]]
2021-10-31 17:08:12.069 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                 ^[(B^[[m [[ True == \T\r\u\e ]]
2021-10-31 17:08:12.074 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                 ^[(B^[[m echo 'exit_trap: cleaning up child processes'
2021-10-31 17:08:12.074 | exit_trap: cleaning up child processes
2021-10-31 17:08:12.080 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:513                 ^[(B^[[m kill 46197
2021-10-31 17:08:12.086 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:517                 ^[(B^[[m '[' -f /tmp/tmp.sxqJzbXUr3 ']'
2021-10-31 17:08:12.092 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:518                 ^[(B^[[m rm /tmp/tmp.sxqJzbXUr3
2021-10-31 17:08:12.152 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                 ^[(B^[[m kill_spinner
2021-10-31 17:08:12.194 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417              ^[(B^[[m '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2021-10-31 17:08:12.222 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                 ^[(B^[[m [[ 3 -ne 0 ]]
2021-10-31 17:08:12.232 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                 ^[(B^[[m echo 'Error on exit'
2021-10-31 17:08:12.232 | Error on exit
2021-10-31 17:08:12.241 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:527                 ^[(B^[[m type -p generate-subunit
2021-10-31 17:08:12.347 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:528                 ^[(B^[[m generate-subunit 1635697928 2164 fail
2021-10-31 17:08:13.812 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:530                 ^[(B^[[m [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2021-10-31 17:08:13.819 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                 ^[(B^[[m /usr/bin/python3.9 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d>
2021-10-31 17:08:30.145 | +^[[38;5;242m./stack.sh:exit_trap:542                 ^[(B^[[m exit 3
```

here's the full log file
[stack.sh.log.2021-10-31-173213](https://zerobin.net/?d7c0fe2f4c892c3b#r9V83QeBmO8Sk82aoBf/YSEg2pnFvTXrOQHoU36iTF8=)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).